# Vuetify form issues

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-cli-3

I've developed a modular popup form using Vuetify, but when i click the email input field and deselect to cause an "empty" error, and then switch over to the register tab, it then causes a "empty" error to the name field.

It seems the issue is linked to the ordering of the text field, because if i then cause the error for my password text field (2nd position for login form), then switch to the register form, the second input field prompts an error.

```
example in link
```

[js fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/L9abgtmh/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `v-if` for the `selectedTab` is triggering a change-notification, so the 2nd form validates (although I don't know why it's only the first 2 fields). Instead, use `v-show`...

```
              <v-card-text v-show="selectedTab == 2">
                    <v-container>
                        <v-form ref="registerForm" v-model="valid" lazy-validation>
                            ...
                        </v-form>
                    </v-container>
              </v-card-text>
              <v-card-text v-show="selectedTab == 1">
                    <v-container>
                        <v-form ref="loginForm" v-model="valid" lazy-validation>
                            ...
                        </v-form>
                    </v-container>
              </v-card-text>
```

https://codeply.com/p/9NtOj5QrPe